# XFCE4.16 - Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS unusable after critical bug manifested - troubleshooting req

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, xfce, ubuntu-studio, debugging

I put desc and a placeholder for this critical bug and solution making is here and https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/-/issues/502 for anyone experiencing a rough XFCE 4.14 -> 4.16 upgrade

Sys: Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit

**The problem:**

https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/-/issues/502

XFCE 4.16 problem manifested in the weird way: I first added multiple indicator as described in gitlab report, then the whole session ejected to login GUI.

From that point, for that user, it successfully logs into the default user, only to log out and shut down X session after approx 8 seconds of restoring XFCE session.

**Speculative thinking on causes:**

could be mix of;

broken dependencies
corrupted session file

**Further practical steps - guidance on how to determine possible culprits appreciated:**

XFCE session data corruption;
-location of XFCE session data
-location of XFCE logs to check what is going on during session restore

X windows system - Input system behaving weird;
a.) firefox input fails like its frozen, and focus to e.g. terminal app, typing few letters, then focus back to firefox resume input
b.) lock screen when XFCE "ask for password" option is ticked (by default) is broken -> X windows input and screen is not functional

That , at least to me, indicates possible component mismatch, package or config problem

Broken dependencies;
-finding and fixing it

Let's see

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see what you're asking, and it feels like this belongs on launchpad (Ubuntu's bug tracker) and not here as bug fixing is off-topic here, this is a user support site. Please see https://docs.xubuntu.org/contributors/qa-bugs.html & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs , I note Yousuf has already stated he suspects it's not a Xfce bug, but Xubuntu packaging so belongs on the Xubuntu bug tracker (launchpad)

Comment: thx @guiverc, thx for your input on that. Will try to move all of that into launchpad.